# NoMethodError in Contacts#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm taking this course on udemy and working through the app I get stuck here! I've rewatched the vids and corrected all I saw. Can someone help me get past this error?

NoMethodError in `Contacts#new`

```
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/contacts/new.html.erb where line #17 raised:
undefined method `comments' for #<Contact:0x007f490a778008>
```

Extracted source (around line #17):

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <%= f.label :name %> 
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %> 
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <%= f.label :email %> 
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :comments %>
        <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control'  %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Am I right on assuming that you have the line `<%= simple_form_for @yorClass do |f| %>` just before this code block?

Comment: This is my routes.rb Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  root 'pages#home'

Comment: so answer is no to your question but video didn<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="well">
      <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :comments %>
          <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control'  %>
        </div>

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is to verify that you are using the `simple_form` structure, which was unclear.... Your question can be better answered if it is self contained. Does your model for the `contacts` have a column called `comments`? (please verify your `schema.rb` file)

Comment: ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150905160857) do

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "text"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end

Comment: I went easy route and just changed 'text' lol I'll swee what happens down the road.

Answer (score 0):

The rails model `Contact` does not seem to have the attribute `comments`, as per your comment this is your current model:

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150905160857) do 
 create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t| 
  t.string "name" 
  t.string "email" 
  t.string "text" 
  t.datetime "created_at" 
  t.datetime "updated_at" 
 end 
end
```

you would have two options:

#### Option 1:

instead of using `comments`, use `text` in your view:

```
<%= f.label :text %>
<%= f.text_area :text, class: 'form-control'  %>
```

#### Option 2:

You could create a new migration to adjust your model renaming the column `text` or adding the column `comments` to your model.

Execute this from the rails app folder:

```
rails g migration adjustingContact
```

navigate to the folder `/your-app-folder/db/migrate` and edit the file `<datestring>_adjustingContact.rb` adding or renaming your `comments` column

execute a migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I hope this helps.